# Unable to install moviepy library of python

Tags: python, visual-studio, gcc, clang, moviepy

In my project I require moviepy library.When Im installing using `pip install moviepy` its giving me this error:

```
WARNING: Failed to activate VS environment: Could not parse vswhere.exe output

      ..\meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Unknown compiler(s): [['icl'], ['cl'], ['cc'], ['gcc'], ['clang'], ['clang-cl'], ['pgcc']]
      The following exception(s) were encountered:
      Running `icl ""` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `cl /?` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `cc --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `gcc --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `clang --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `clang-cl /?` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `pgcc --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
```

I do have Microsoft Visual Studio installed and its path is : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer"